# Keep URL while surfing data Structure in Django web app

Tags: python, django, url, filepath, file-structure

I am attempting to create a django based website.  The goal of one part of the site is to show the contents of a database in reference to its file structure.

I would like to keep the URL the same while traveling deeper into the file structure, as opposed to developing another view for each level of the file structure a person goes into.

The simplest way I can think to achieve this is to pass the current directory path in the ***request*** variable but I am not sure how to do this or if it is possible since it would have to be linked in the html file, and not the view file that is written in python.

If you are able to at very least point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to avoid urls like `www.example.com/db-contents/?level=2`? Passing variables in through request.GET like that is the normal way to do it. All the requests will go to the same url and view, and you can just do `request.GET['level']` in the template.

If you absolutely want the url to stay completely static (`` `www.example.com/db-contents/ ``) then you can send and receive your data via AJAX calls.

by adding `?foo=bar` to the url it means you can access the 'foo' key in the `request.GET` dictionary, and the value of that key will be `"bar"`. for multiple variables you separate with the `&` symbol.

For example:

```
www.example.com/db-contents/?foo=bar&somevar=1&anothervar=

>>> request.GET['foo']
'bar'
>>> request.GET['somevar']
'1'
>>> request.GET['anothervar']
None
>>> "anothervar" in request.GET
True
>>> "notsetvar" in request.GET
False
```

Comment: The first example of `www.example.com/db-contents/?level=2` would be alright, except there are multiple options for level 2 meaning that I cannot just change level=2 to level=3 for the next level down.  If the file structure goes into say 7 levels, the most strightforward way to code that from what I see is to have a url of 
`www.example.com/db-contents/?levelname2/?levelname3/?levelname4/?levelname5/?levelname6/?levelname7`
I was hoping there would be an easy way to avoid this without going to any type of JS

Comment: the request variables aren't part of the URL per se (you don't need a slash in between them). They're key/value pairs much like a python dictionary. Could you give an example of the db structure you want to display? Currently I'm not sure what you mean by levelname2, levelname3 etc

Comment: your "you dont need a slash in between them" just potentially cleared everything up.  I can just send the directory structure from the url but using `www.example.com/db-contents/?leve1-level2-leve3` where i can just convert this to the directory path in the function.  I have to decide what character to use for path separation though.  Thanks, I think this has lead to a different question now.

Comment: Lifesaver=you
Thanks for the update.  That is even better than what I was thinking of doing!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into forms on the Django documentation site. When the user submits the form the appropriate file structure information will be passed to your view code. The view code can then pass the new file structure information to your template. The template will create the forms and the process will start over again.

Comment: Forms was an interesting way to go about it, but from what i see in the documentation, it would mostly need a user text input and I was hoping for a click and go.

Comment: Remember, that any text input can be hidden from the user but still passed when the form's submit button is clicked. The nice thing about using a form is that you can use POST instead of GET and thus not worry about the URL parameters. But it really comes down to what's best/easiest for your particular situation.